# How to define a python class at runtime with a dynamic inheritance chain?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I  need an expert's help with the Python type system. Can I do something like:

```
class I(object): pass
class A(I): pass
class B(I): pass
my_parents = [A, B]
class C(*my_parents): pass
```

Basically I want to determine the inheritance chain at runtime, avoiding any potential issues resulting from the diamond problem. What's the best way to do something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define classes dynamically using the [3-argument form of `type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type):

```
C = type('C', tuple(my_parents), {})
```

---

```
class I(object): pass
class A(I): pass
class B(I): pass
my_parents = [A, B]
# class C(*my_parents): pass # works in Python3 but not in Python2
C = type('C', tuple(my_parents), {})
print(C.__bases__)
```

yields

```
(<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>)
```

---

Note: I don't know what you mean by "avoiding any potential issues resulting from the diamond problem". You *will* have an inheritance diamond if you use `A` and `B` as bases of `C`. If the issue you are referring to is how to call parent methods, the solution of course is to use [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super).